# CSS - image sprite :active not working ie

Tags: css, css-sprites, sliding-doors

Here is my code, which works perfectly in all but ie! The active simply does not fire

```
    a.Button span {
background: transparent url('images/form_sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0;
display: block;
height:45px;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 7px 0 5px 20px;
color: #fff;
background-position: 0 -44px;
}

a.Button {
background: transparent url('images/form_sprite.png') no-repeat top right;
display: block;
float: left;
height: 45px;
margin-right: 6px;
padding-right: 27px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
}

a.Button:hover span {
background-position: 0 -136px;
}

a.Button:hover {
background-position: right -90px;
}

a.Button:active span {
background-position: 0 -225px;
}

a.Button:active {
background-position: right -181px;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="clearbutton"> <a class="Button" href="#"><span>Button text</span></a> </div>
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: which versions of IE? 6 - 7 - 8 - 9?

Comment: if you add another effect to the :active, such as a color change, does it fire in IE?

Comment: @Aninemity - no, that doesn't work either

Comment: can you add the html code so i can try a couple of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `a.Button:active` to `a.Button span:active` in your css. That seems to be firing the `:active` css and still works in chrome for me.

Comment: this works to a degree, but, as this is a sliding door type class there are two halves to it - changed it to what you said and now clicking either half does work but does not fire both together - nightmare this

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the `:active` psuedo-class only fires in IE when the user is clicking *directly* on that object. In this case, the link. If you're clicking on a child object (the span), the link's active event won't fire.

You can, as Aninemity said, apply the style to `span:active` (the proper way to do this). But in IE6/7, `:active` fires only for links. If you need IE6/7 support, you'll have to find some way to get rid of the span.